# cannot display json data from rest service in html page with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a problem when i want to show some records from my databse in html page : **i have an empty array in html page**.
I have a restful service that shows my json data : http://localhost:8080/produits

[{"id":1,"designation":"HP CDG","prix":123.0,"quantite":456},{"id":2,"designation":"Samsung galaxy","prix":905.0,"quantite":7}]

I am using spring boot application

the javascript file :  app.js

```
var app = angular.module("MyApp",[])
app.controller("ProduitController",function($scope,$http){
$scope.produits=null;
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/produits")
.success(function(data){

    $scope.produits=data;
})
.error(function(err){
    console.log(err);

})

});
```

my index.html page :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<title>catalogue</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="ProduitController">
    <h3>Test</h3>
    <div class="Container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Designation</th>
                <th>Prix</th>
                <th>Quantite</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="p in produits">
                <td>{{p.id}}</td>
                <td>{{p.designation}}</td>
                <td>{{p.prix}}</td>
                <td>{{p.quantite}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that your problem come for the initialization of the products before the call to $http. Can you remove it and try again.

Comment: I did but the same problem..

Comment: Calling http://localhost:8080/produits in web browser, do you have a result?

Comment: I see that you hardcoded the URL to your REST service. Is your app running on another port ?

Comment: in your success callback log the data to the console and see what you're getting back.

Comment: my app is running in 8080, the console is not printing anything

Comment: I resolved the problem by using <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  it was a version conflit